# Implicit type predicate

Tags: typescript

I have a React provider that exports a `user` object as well as a `isAuthenticated` method that checks the local `user` value. I want to make this method a type predicate, but I believe I've hit a design limitation of TypeScript. For sake of simplicity i've stripped away the React stuff and wrote a simplified version.

I'd like it if I just had to call `isAuthenticated()` without passing in the `user` reference, and then have the `user` reference type guarded. See the `IntendedComponent` function for an example.

```js
type User = {
    name: string
}

const AuthProvider = () => {
    let user: User | undefined = undefined

    const setUser = (_user: User) => user = _user

    // It should be possible for this type predicate to guard the local `user` variable reference
    const isAuthenticated = (user?: User): user is User => 
        user !== null && user !== undefined

    // An ideal implementation would be where the `user` references the `user` defined on the first line of this function
    // const isAuthenticated = (): user is User => 
    //     user !== null && user !== undefined

    return {
        user,
        setUser,
        isAuthenticated
    }
}

function Component() {
    const { user, setUser, isAuthenticated } = AuthProvider()

    // required to pass the user reference even though the isAuthenticated method already has the user variable closure
    if (isAuthenticated(user)) {
        // user is guarded and we can safely use it
    } else {
        // user is not guarded unsafe to use
    }
}

function IntendedComponent() {
    const { user, setUser, isAuthenticated } = AuthProvider()

    if (isAuthenticated()) {
        // user is guarded and we can safely use it
    } else {
        // user is not guarded unsafe to use
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the design limitation you mentioned? In other words, what's the problem here?

Comment: I've tried to clarify my question. Pleas see the edit!